# Bootstrap card has white trim around image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Followed the example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_cards.asp) with the following code:

```
<div class="card" style="width:400px">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="image.png" alt="Card image">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Some example text.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

which gives a white border around the image (just inside the grey area). I am not applying any other CSS:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.card` has a default border set to : `border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);`

To remove this border, simply add the class `border-0` to your `<div>` like so :

```
<div class="card border-0" style="width:400px">
```

See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#border for more information

Comment: Simplest solution.

Comment: @user8897013 Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

The example you followed also has a white border since this is done by Bootstrap. You are not applying any other CSS but this is exactly what you should do to get rid of the border.

For example: apply `border:0px solid transparent;` to the object with the `card` class.

Comment: Why doesn't it show up in the example from the link at the top? I'm curious because I think this is an error. Truth is, there used to be no white border in my site and it appeared out of nowhere, and I don't know why.

Comment: It *does* show up in the example. You just can't see it because the background is also white.

Answer (score 0):

write `.card: border: none;` bescuase .card has default gray border class.